# Update specific cell via python in html

Tags: python, sql-server, django

im making a website that displays an object from the database with associated items(foreginKey). As of now i list the components in a table and it works fine. Also works with refresh to update the values. But i want only the cell with the dynamic value to update without calling the refresh to reload the whole page to stop flickering images etc.

Havent really tried much as im not so good at this, tho i figured that i need som "id" on the  to make it targetable perhaps? Also i think i need to put the .value outside the initial for loop and maybe loop it seperatly inside SetInterval function. But how do I do that?

I am using Django 2.1.4 / Python 3.7.1 / Win10 / MSSQL running on localhost at the moment.

Also my first question here so hope the formatting is good.

```
<h2>{{ object.name }}</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Description</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Fabrikat</th>
                  <th>Type</th>
                  <th>Value</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
{% for komponent in object.komponent_set.all %}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ komponent.beskrivning }}</td>
                  <td>{{ komponent.namn }}</td>
                  <td>{{ komponent.fabrikat }}</td>
                  <td>{{ komponent.typ }}</td>
                  <td>{{ komponent.value }}</td>
                </tr>
{% endfor %}
    <script>
var myVar = setInterval(valueRefresh, 5000);

function valueRefresh() {
    {% for komponent in aggregat.komponent_set.all %};

                  <td>{{ komponent.value }}</td>;

    {% endfor %};

}
</script>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
```

Sorry if this is rookie hour, but i dont know how to go about this.

Comment: what you probably need for this purpose is AJAX